# How to swap by Karabiner option+shift+brightness and brightness

Tags: macos, keyboard, big-sur, karabiner

How to swap the behaviour of <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>brightness</kbd> (e.g. changing the brightness in small increments) and the normal <kbd>brightness</kbd> key in Karabiner?

I tried

```
{
    "title": "Screen brightness in smaller steps",
    "rules": [
        {
            "description": "Screen brightness in smaller step",
            "manipulators": [
                {
                    "type": "basic",
                    "from": <%= from("apple_vendor_top_case_key_code":"brightness_down") %>,
                    "to": <%= to([["apple_vendor_top_case_key_code":"brightness_down", ["shift"], ["left_option"]], ["vk_none"]]) %>
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

but the brightness key still changes the brightness in big steps.

In case it makes any difference, I'm using MacOS 11.5 with the expanded control slip on the touch bar and an external mac keyboard with normal media keys

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question but couldn't find the answer on the web. I created these tools for import to Karabiner. It works well for version 14.3.

I hope you'll get a chance to see my response and that the tools can help you well!

Decrease Display Brightness by small increments using F1. Equivalent to using option + shift
Long press, fast [here](https://genesy.github.io/karabiner-complex-rules-generator/#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).

Increase Display Brightness by small increments using F2. Equivalent to using option + shift
Long press, fast [here](https://genesy.github.io/karabiner-complex-rules-generator/#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).

Answer (score 0):

The following configuration does not swap the behaviour, but it at least maps the touch bar brightness buttons to <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>brightness</kbd> (needs Karabiner v13.3.0 or newer)

```
{
    "description": "Display brightness in small steps",
    "manipulators": [
        {
            "from": {
                "apple_vendor_top_case_key_code": "brightness_down"
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "key_code": "display_brightness_decrement",
                    "modifiers": [
                        "left_shift",
                        "left_option"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "type": "basic"
        },
        {
            "from": {
                "apple_vendor_top_case_key_code": "brightness_up"
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "key_code": "display_brightness_increment",
                    "modifiers": [
                        "left_shift",
                        "left_option"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "type": "basic"
        }
    ]
}
```